# Removing the little box from a toggle button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I've this toggle button:

```
public Texture2D togglebutton;

hydro.t1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 155, 100, 50), hydro.t1Bool, togglebutton);
```

everything is fine, in my scene I added a texture to the variable togglebutton but I can't get rid of the toggle button little box (that has a white square when the bool is true and empty otherwise). Can you help me? I just want the texture to be the button.

[see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dStt.png)

Comment: ah, you CAN NOT now use the extremely old "gui" system.  it is deprecated, being removed from Unity (see their blog), and doesn't really work.  note that it is INCREDIBLY easy to do this with the ordinry UI system in unity.  (1) addd canvas (usually select "scale to screen size"), (2) click "add checkbox"  you're done

Comment: And scripting is the old method?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhB-vTEZtg4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as legacy GUI is not recomended to use (as @**Joe Blow** says) any more, you can do it with custom `GUISkin`:

```
GUI.skin = skin; 
hydro.t1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 155, 100, 50), hydro.t1Bool, togglebutton);
```

What you need to do is to create `GUISkin` within editor, have reference to it in your script, and assign it in the begining of `OnGUI()` method as shown.

Take a look into `GUISkin` in inspector, find Toggle tab and play with it to remove the "tick" image.